# Replace a hyphen surrounded by numbers with a dash

Tags: regex, ms-word

I would like to replace a hyphen (-) with a dash (–) when a hyphen is surrounded by from one digit to three. E.g.:

1-2

12-13

444-555

In Word the following works for one digit:

`([0-9])-([0-9])`

replace regex: `\1–\2`

However, the following fails to work – shows an error.

`(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})`

replace regex: `\1–\2`

Comment: Digits on both side should be equal in length ?

Comment: I haven't thought about this. Let assume they should be equal.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with the very limited ms-word regex, if you don't insist on equal length, you could use `([0-9]{1;})-([0-9]{1;})` as a search pattern, your replace is already correct

Comment: Which office suite are you using ?

Comment: @SebastianProske It works but it catches more than three digits. I use Office 2016.

Comment: Yes, sorry, to late to edit my comment - use `<([0-9]{1;3})-([0-9]{1;3})>`, this will also avoid matching `a1-1a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to escape dash with `\`.

Try this.

```
<([0-9]{1;4})\-([0-9]{1;4})>
```

It is not required in Word 2010 but might be required in '16.

Comment: It does the trick. `{1;4}` should be replaced with `{1;3}` to allow for only 3 digits. Thank you. I wish Microsoft were more consistent with its RegExp.

Comment: Microsoft uses very simple wild card so that it is easy to understood for non programmer while regex is for programmers so please don't expect from Microsoft.